# Trailing slash remove bug with htaccess and apache server

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/(.*)/exam$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/exam$ exampage.php?vname=$1&ecode=$2 [L]
```

i want URL like "mysite.com/hp/000-120/exam" but the above code is not working 
can any body help?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with just the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/exam$ exampage.php?vname=$1&ecode=$2 [L]
```

Comment: i m using this rule in htaccess "RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)-certifications/([^/]+)-exams$ certpage.php?cname=$1 [L]" but its not working what i want is "mysite.com/hp-certifications/emc-exam

Comment: What value is your script expecting to be passed, as your rule will set cname="hp"